# GWT widget for displaying ppt(power point presentations)

Tags: java, gwt

I would like to use a GWT widget for displaying the ppt into my webapp.
The ppt can be stored on the server itself or some other server.

Is there any one who have done this before or does GWT have a widget to support this kind of requirement.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any GWT widget doing this but it's damn easy to do it yourself.
Use the following service to generate the iframe code for an embedded document viewer : https://docs.google.com/viewer

This will give you the base html code to use, then simply create a widget producing the very same html code changing only the actual document URL.

Done! :)

Hope this helps.

/Paul